# passing javascript parameters and using them in unity C# files

Tags: c#, javascript, unity-game-engine

I want to pass some javascript parameters at runtime (webplayer) to unity and using them in my network.cs script.

```
<html>
     <script type="text/JavaScript">
        //<![CDATA[
          PlayerName = "Adam";
          playerID = "56";
        //]]>
    </script>
</html>
```

Just consider I am using the above parameters to log in users.

Answer (score 1):

You need to send the data from the webpage to the Unity3d container. You can do something like this:

```
u.getUnity().SendMessage(GameObjectName,MethodName,stringParam);
```

where:

u is the Unity3d container object created by unity if you use their template.

GameObjectName is the name of a game object that you placed somewhere on the stage

MethodName is the name of a method that's available for that GameObject, that means that it will be a method defined in one of the components (MonoBehaviour) that you attached the the GameObject

stringParam si the parameter that you pass to MethodName, the method can only accept one string param, so you need to serialize your data, you can use JSON.parse( {"playerName":PlayerName,"playerId":playerID} )

On the C#/Unity side you need to implement a MonoBheviour that has a

```
void MethodName(string param);
```

defined that reads the string and with a JSON parser gets the data out.

Comment: This sounds like a much better, more specific answer to unity3d

Answer (score 0):

You would need to post that data back to your server. Using AJAX is probably want you want if you don't want your whole page to reload.

A commonly used framework, facilitating ajax is [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

You would need an endpoint, writting in your c# (guessing from your fileending on network.cs) to read what your clientside javascript is posting. I don't know what version of .net you are on, but look into WebAPI - it is very easy to implement.

TL;DR

1. Use javascript/jquery to post your data from the client to the server.
2. Read the posted data on your serverside, though either WebAPI or just a normal .aspx page reading querystring/form values

If you just want to send data from the client, and not worry about any response, you can use

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: {PlayerName: PlayerName, PlayerId: playerID},
});
```

You can change `POST` to `GET` if you want the make a get request instead. The data will be readable through `Request.Form` or `Request.QueryString` if you use a normal .aspx page for `url`. If you use WebAPI, it will be injected into your methods parameters.

Comment: Thanks, any example of jquery method ?

Comment: And one more question when I send the data how to use it in C# file ? Any reference or example of that ?

Comment: That depends on what kind of solution you have. Do you have a website already? Are you already hosting an endpoint of some kind?

Comment: Yes , and it is based on PHP/MYSQL project.